# Prolog cut after a fact

Tags: prolog, logic

I'm in Prolog and i have this fact:

```
likes(mary,juice).
```

I want to put a cut after this fact

```
likes(mary,juice),!.
```

But the Prolog compiler doesn't allow me to do that. Why it's uncorrect ? ( I want to prevent backtracking after this fact is chosen)

Comment: Because `cut` is a goal. Putting a goal after a fact is not a valid syntax in prolog.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent backtracking after choosing this fact? I suspect the overall problem you are trying to solve likely has a better solution than that.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment suggested, you have to turn the fact into a rule put the cut into the rule's body:

```
likes(mary, juice) :-
    !.
```

(The usual warnings about cut apply. It can change your program's meaning in ways you don't expect and should be avoided unless you know exactly what you're doing *and* you really need the speedup it provides.)